# Changing the src of an iframe with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have an embedded Youtube video and when I click on an  tag, it changes the iframe scr to an other Youtube video. The page should not reload completely, only the iframe if needed and the src it must be able to change again by clicking a different link.

Please help if possible!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with modifying element attributes/properties via JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page?rq=1 this might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a normal link, but its [`target` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) is the ID of the `<iframe>` you want to load it into. Example:

```
<a href="http://example.com/page1" target="myframe">Page 1</a>
<a href="http://example.com/page2" target="myframe">Page 2</a>

<iframe name="myframe" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

Of course, you will need to know the ID of the frame (if it has one) and how to format the link to insert.